# Need assistance in executing SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am quite new to SQL Server

This is my table structure:

```
id      int 
name    string
value   int
```

Sample data:

```
id name value 
-------------
1  a    20
2  b    30
3  c    10
4  d    50
5  e    60
6  f    60
```

I need to get this result

```
id name value rank
------------------
1  a    20    2
2  b    30    3
3  c    10    1
4  d    50    4
5  e    60    5
6  f    60    5
```

I tried this query after some search I got this

```
SELECT 
   *, rank = ROW_NUMBER(OVER ORDER BY value) 
FROM table
```

But it does not seem to be getting what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

```
select *,DENSE_RANK() OVER 
    (order by value) AS Rank
from Table1
order by id
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    VALUE   RANK
1   a       20      2
2   b       30      3
3   c       10      1
4   d       50      4
5   e       60      5
6   f       60      5
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fa6e/33).

Read more about `DENSE_RANK` [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx).

Comment: Downvoter: Explain why? Is it because I have provided the correct answer at the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Use `RANK` in place of `ROW_NUMBER` to get the ranking (use `DENSE_RANK` if you did want the rankings to go 1, 2, 3, 4, rather than 1, 2, 3, 5, 6)

Answer (score 0):

Any one of these should work:

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS rank
FROM table 


SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS rank
FROM table
```

Comment: OP says, he already tried `ROW_NUMBER()` but didn't get the result.

Comment: Ya.. but your original post uses `ROW_NUMBER`. That won't get OP the desired result.

Comment: @RagingBull Yes. He didn't get the desired result. Because the syntax is wrong. Anyways, sorry. I have made the desired changes